# How to script remote monitoring and management

Tags: script, webserver, administrator, perl, client-server

Looking at this video on scripting:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcERIxWDQXA

how or where is this executed?  What I'm not understanding is how to use the SWIS (SolarWinds Information Service) with N-Central to query the server itself.  It looks like Orion is a seperate product.  Does this mean that N-Central doesn't support SWIS type queries or scripting as Orion does?

Currently using N-Central for remote monitoring and management.

Solarwinds does offer a powershell module, as well.

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55553630/262852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video concerns the Orion family of SolarWinds products (Network Performance Monitor, Server and Application Monitor, Network Configuration Manager, etc.). SolarWinds Information Service is part of the Orion platform. N-Central does not use the Orion platform and does not have SWIS or support its API.

To get started with the N-Central API, start here: https://support.solarwindsmsp.com/kb/solarwinds_n-central/Accessing-SolarWinds-N-central-API-functions